# Best Car stereo for my android phone

Tags: htc-evo, bluetooth, audio

I just got a HCT EVO and was thinking about getting car stereo with bluetooth, car mount, and car charger to go with it (for my 2005 Civic).

First of all, are there any products that will do all of these?  A mount/charger that can also be hooked into the car audio?  It doesn't even have to be bluetooth if it can just directly hook my phone into the car speakers, but I haven't been able to find anything like this.

Otherwise, I am having trouble finding a minimal bluetooth device... I don't really need anything features except routing bluetooth to my car audio, because my phone does everything else.

I am also concerned that I've read some reviews that say they only work with the phones **bluetooth calling and not with playing media**.  I'd like to be able to listen to pandora in the car.  How can I make sure that when I see "bluetooth" I can know it supports both?

Can anyone give me some tips on what to look for or where to look?  Are these things hard to install yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the device supports [A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29) and [AVRCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Audio.2FVideo_Remote_Control_Profile_.28AVRCP.29).  You'll find many handsfree kits that connect to your stereo support those (it's what I use) - check out [Parrot's range](http://www.parrot.com/usa/products/bluetooth-hands-free-car-kits) for examples.

Then you can use a separate mount and charger so that when you replace your phone you don't have to replace everything.

Answer (score 1):

You might just use the audio jack.  I know this works with headphones when making calls, maybe it would work with playing the audio through speakers too?

Comment: Except I don't have one :-(.  There don't seem to be any cheap ways around this either.

Answer (score 1):

For the "minimal bluetooth device" -- It sounds like your minimum is streaming Bluetooth audio (calls & media) to the stereo. For that, I've found the [Motorola T505](http://amzn.com/B001HTX4BA) to work well with Android. It pairs via Bluetooth to your phone and has a built in FM transmitter to send audio to your stereo. It handled music and calls very well on my Samsung Vibrant with 2.1 & 2.2 so your EVO should be fine. As far as redundant features -- Only that it also functions as a standalone speakerphone, which I considered more a perk than problem.